# PHP doc: state that you are returning the result of another function call

Tags: phpdoc

With a function like this:

```
function cancel($thing_id)
{
   $this->Thing->id = $thing_id;
   return $this->Thing->cancel();
}
```

How do I format the @return to reflect that I am returning the result of another function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to link the return type to a different functions return type. It is not mentioned as a type in [phpDocumentor: Defining a 'Type'](https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/types.html), and the closest thing would be the `callable` type.

The best thing you can do probably is the following:

```
/**
 * As a example I have assumed that $this->Thing->cancel() returns either true or false
 *
 * @see Thing::cancel
 * @return bool Returns the result of Thing::cancel
 */
```

As you can see, I specify the return type of `$this->Thing->cancel()` and explain where the return type originates from. To make it easy to find the method I added the `@see` tag, pointing to the method